# F# - generating a list of tuples from integer input

Tags: list, f#, tuples, collect

I'm supposed to return a list of tuples from an integer input. 
For example: 
**output' 4** should return a list of tuples:

```
[(1, 1);
(2, 1); (2, 2);
(3, 1); (3, 2); (3, 3);
(4, 1); (4, 2); (4, 3); (4, 4)]
```

At the moment I'm getting

```
 [(1, 1); (1, 2); (1, 3); (1, 4);
 (2, 1); (2, 2); (2, 3); (2, 4);
 (3, 1);(3, 2); (3, 3); (3, 4);
 (4, 1); (4, 2); (4, 3); (4, 4)]
```

What I have so far:

```
let output' x =
    let ls= [1..x]
    ls |> List.collect (fun x ->[for i in ls -> x,i])    
output' 4
```

I can't figure out how to get the needed output. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a filter:

```
...
|> List.filter (fun (a, b) -> a >= b)`
```

or

```
let output x =
    [ for i in 1..x do
      for j in 1..i do yield (i,j)
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

In F# they mostly work with sequences, so here is a sequence-driven lazy solution:

```
let output' max =
    let getTuples x = 
        seq { 1 .. x }
        |> Seq.map (fun y -> (x, y))

    seq { 1 .. max }
    |> Seq.map getTuples
```

If you need lists, replace `seq { 1 .. x }` with `[ 1 .. x ]`.
It will still be more functional-way than loops.